# Possible to install linux on an android tablet?

Tags: linux, multi-boot, tablet

Is it possible to install linux on a rooted Android tablet?

I like the look of the Asus Transformer Prime, but would really like to be able to dual boot so I can run normal programs on it and treat it like a laptop (I'd be using it for coding and writing using a java program).

Does anyone know if dual-booting tablets and installing linux is possible?

Thanks

apparently it is according to youtube.

Comment: I'm sure you mean a different version of Linux, but just for clarity Android is a Linux variant.  I am not aware of a way to install a more traditional Linux distro on something like the Transformer, but I am sure some enterprising people will fix that soon if there isn't one now.

Comment: Android is already linux.  Android already runs java programs.  Your question makes no sense.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is a project for running Debian beside Android (one such is called [Lil' Debi](https://guardianproject.info/2011/06/18/easy-installer-for-debian-on-android/)). Strangely, I can't find any NetBSD projects for Android tablets.

Comment: @andy This maybe useful http://liliputing.com/2013/04/ubuntu-touch-preview-is-about-to-get-its-first-apps-for-phones-tablets.html

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://stream0.org/2011/11/24/dual-booting-android-and-linux-on-asus-transformer-part-two/) is a link to a guide to "Dual Booting Android and Linux on Asus Transformer Part Two".
[Here](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/39299-romwip-ubuntu-touch-on-d2vzw-dev-previewphantom-022213/) is a more up-to-date information(22 February 2013) - for Linux Ubuntu Touch.
And there is also information on [how to install Plasma Active](http://community.kde.org/Plasma/Active/Installation), which is Linux with a Tablet oriented, KDE-based shell.

I hope it helps you.